# form doesnt send data with post method

Tags: php, forms, post

It echos "empty".. please help, i cant find the problem!
Both of them called by AJAX. The first code creates a new TR into a table.
I'd like to send data to the other php with the addnewTape() function.
But the POST array is empty.

New TR into a table (newtapeTR.php):

```
echo "<form id='tapeform".$_SESSION['newtape']."' method='POST' action=''>";
echo "<td> <input type='text' value='".$_SESSION['newtape']."' name='tapeid' readonly style='width: 25px;'></td>";
echo "<td> <input type='text' placeholder='citation' name='tapetext' style='width: 625px;'> </td>";
echo "<td id='tapeadd".$_SESSION['newtape']."' colspan='2'> <input type='button' onClick='addnewTape(".$_SESSION['newtape'].");' value='Add' class='button' ></td>";
echo "</form>";
```

form submitting, with AJAX function (example:) addnewTape(32)
newtape.php:

```
if (empty($_POST)) 
{
echo "empty";
}
else 
{
$tapeid = $_POST['tapeid']; //this should be 32
$tapetext = $_POST['tapetext']; //this should be some text
}
```

Ajax:

```
function addtapeTR(){ 
    var xmlhttp; 
    var tapetableRef = document.getElementById('tapetitle'); 
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { 
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
    } else { 
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); 
    } 
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() { 
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) { 
                var newRow = tapetableRef.insertRow(-1); 
                var lastRowIndex = tapetableRef.rows.length-1; 
                var newID = lastRowIndex-1; 
                newID++; 
                newRow.id = "tape"+newID; 
                newRow.innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText; 
            } 
    } 
    xmlhttp.open("POST","menu-main/menu-setting-submenu/newtapeTR.php",true);       
    xmlhttp.send(); 
}
```

This ajax calls the newtape.php, and sends the id, and the text:

```
function addnewTape(id) {
    var id = id-1;

    if (tapeid[id].value=="" || tapetext[id].value=="") {
        alert('Empty field!');
    } else {
        $.ajax({ 
            type: "POST",
            url: "menu-main/menu-setting-submenu/newtape.php",
            data: $("#tapeform"+(id+1)).serialize(),
            success: function(data){
            $("#tape"+(id+1)).html(data);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

ANSWER:
Something went wrong with the data here:

```
data: $("#tapeform"+(id+1)).serialize(),
```

I did it without jQuery, and GET. Now it works. Any tips, what went wrong in this line?

Comment: Can you show us your AJAX?

Comment: I'd check `$_GET` in case the ajax is sending a GET request.

Comment: sorry, it is a bit long.
Jim, $_GET also gets empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
xmlhttp.send();
```

This line sends the request but doesn't send any data along with it.

```
var data = {"foo":"bar"};//Get this from the form.
xmlhttp.send(data);
```

JQuery provides a nice method to convert a form to a variable:

```
var data = $( "#form_id" ).serialize();
```

Other libraries probably have this too. If you don't want to use a library you can build up the array manually by looping over the forms elements.

Comment: It doesnt have to send data, it only creates a new line into a table. I added the ajax which calls the newtape.php, which needs the data

Answer (score 0):

There are two elements in array and this definitely doesn't mean that array is empty. As a quick workaround you can do following:

```
$errors = array_filter($_POST);

if (empty($errors)) {
echo "empty";
}
else 
{
$tapeid = $_POST['tapeid']; //this should be 32
$tapetext = $_POST['tapetext']; //this should be some text
}
```

array_filter() function's default behavior will remove all values from array which are equal to null, 0, '' or false

otherwise in your particular case empty() construct will always return true if there is at least one element even with "empty" value.

Comment: `empty()` will only return true for an array if the array has no elements.

Comment: We are copying $_POST data to $empty so how its value can become undefined ??

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: tapeid in D:\xampp\htdocs\protea\menu-main\menu-setting-submenu\newtape.php on line 11

Line 11: $tapeid = $_POST['tapeid'];